# Is this a solid database design that passes 3rd normal form?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema, relational-theory

I am a tennis coach and created a small database to track student testing. I have several programs( beginner, intermediate, advanced).  And Throughout the year/season, they are divided into four 8 week sessions. At the end of each session, I perform proficiency testing on each student. It’s basically a tennis accuracy, conditioning, and mental written test, divided by certain categories and objectives. The test can change each 8 week session(i want to be able to add or change the proficiency category, objective, and score_attempts attributes),
but only one test “predefined template” can be used per session on all students.
All students take the same test per session, but again, usually I modify or add to the test each subsequent session but not always.

Addtl rules:

1. A student can only belong to one program, but they can be moved into different programs ( between sessions only, not in the middle of a session).
   Only one test type/template is used per session and for all students( all students take the same test).
2. Changes to the test format/template only can happen between sessions.  Between sessions, it is common that new categories and objectives are added or deleted.
   or that the score_attempts number is modified (the max score number per objective).
3. If a category or objective is removed, I want to retain the scores from previous sessions for that objective.
4. For now, a student can only take the test once per session (but in future might want it to be possible for a student to do a retest,
   so they could take the same test twice in the same session)

Here are the entities(with sample domain data):
Program(advanced), Program Session(session1,2,3,4), Proficiency category(forehand,backhand, volley,conditioning, mental test), Proficiency objective(subclass of category. Ie:for forehand category, there are 3 objective or test components: make 10 forehand shots to target a, then b, and c.  So i record how many out of 10 they make to each target), Proficiency Test template(the category and objective set for a test), Proficiency test template session (bridge table between template and session), Proficiency Test (records the scores/results of test).

**I think my main question surrounds the template and session relationship and where to put the score_attempts attribute? Or if there is just a better, more correct way to
model this so that I can enhance it later (I will be creating different tests for different program in the future.  And adding student goal tracking.  And track
student attributes at a more detailed level than session, like weekly, daily, etc.**

--Here is the sql code (for SQL server).  (You can copy and paste into an SSMS window and execute)

```
use master 
drop database if exists tennis_test
go

create database tennis_TEST
go

use tennis_TEST
go

create schema Eval
go

drop table if exists eval.student
create table eval.student(
student_id          int             IDENTITY(1,1)       NOT NULL,
first_name          varchar(50)                         NOT NULL,
last_name           varchar(50)                         NOT NULL,
--phone             char(12)                            NULL,
phone               varchar(50)                         NULL,
email               varchar(50)                         NULL,
DOB                 date                                NULL,
note                varchar(8000)                       NULL,
in_transition       char(1)                             NULL,
is_active           char(1)                             NULL,
constraint pk_student_id    PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
)

drop table if exists eval.program
create table eval.program(
program_id          int             IDENTITY(1,1)       NOT NULL,
program_desc        varchar(50)                         NOT NULL,
constraint pk_program_id    PRIMARY KEY (program_id)
)

drop table if exists eval.program_session
create table eval.program_session(
program_session_id      int             IDENTITY(1,1)       NOT NULL,
program_id          int                                 NOT NULL, 
session_desc        varchar(50)                         NOT NULL,
season              varchar(50)                         NOT NULL,
session_start_date  smalldatetime                       NOT NULL,
session_end_date    smalldatetime                       NOT NULL,
constraint pk_program_session_id    PRIMARY KEY(program_session_id),
constraint fk_program_session_program_id FOREIGN KEY (program_id) REFERENCES eval.program(program_id) 
)

drop table if exists eval.proficiency_category
create table eval.proficiency_category(
proficiency_category_id             int     NOT NULL,
shot_category                       varchar(50) NOT NULL,
shot_category_desc                  varchar(200),
constraint pk_proficiency_category_id PRIMARY KEY(proficiency_category_id)
)

drop table if exists eval.proficiency_objective
create table eval.proficiency_objective(
proficiency_objective_id        int     NOT NULL,
proficiency_category_id         int     NOT NULL,
shot_objective                  varchar(200),
shot_objective_desc             varchar(200),
score_attempts                  smallint,    -- -- this is the max number of shots attempted for each objective 
--not sure where to put score_attempts this so I have duplicated the column in multiple tables 
constraint pk_proficiency_objective_id PRIMARY KEY(proficiency_objective_id),
constraint fk_proficiency_category_id FOREIGN KEY (proficiency_category_id) REFERENCES eval.proficiency_category(proficiency_category_id),
-- added this constraint to show that I update this table when I need to change a score attempts number for an existing objective.  For example, 
constraint uq_objective_score UNIQUE (shot_objective, score_attempts)
)

drop table if exists eval.proficiency_test_template
create table eval.proficiency_test_template(
proficiency_test_template_id    int     IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
template_num                    int     NOT NULL,
proficiency_objective_id        int     NOT NULL,
score_attempts                  smallint,           
constraint fk_template_proficiency_objective FOREIGN KEY (proficiency_objective_id) REFERENCES eval.proficiency_objective(proficiency_objective_id)
)

--This table must be updated each session to tie a template to the session's test.  It could be the same template as last session.
drop table if exists eval.proficiency_test_template_session
create table eval.proficiency_test_template_session(
proficiency_test_template_session_id    int     IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
template_num                            int NOT NULL,
program_session_id                      int     NOT NULL,
constraint fk_template_session FOREIGN KEY (program_session_id) REFERENCES eval.program_session(program_session_id) 
)

drop table if exists eval.proficiency_test
create table eval.proficiency_test(
student_id                  int     NOT NULL,
program_id                  int     NOT NULL,
program_session_id          int     NOT NULL,
proficiency_category_id     int     NOT NULL,
proficiency_objective_id    int     NOT NULL,
score                       smallint,
constraint pk_proficiency_test PRIMARY KEY (student_id,program_id,program_session_id,proficiency_category_id,proficiency_objective_id)
)  -- No FKs defined yet

-- Load sample data.  CSV files must exist on local c:\temp drive 
BULK INSERT eval.student
FROM 'c:\temp\student.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\student_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)

BULK INSERT eval.program
FROM 'c:\temp\program.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\program_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)

BULK INSERT eval.program_session
FROM 'c:\temp\program_session.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\program_session_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)

BULK INSERT eval.proficiency_category
FROM 'c:\temp\proficiency_category.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\proficiency_category_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)

BULK INSERT eval.proficiency_objective
FROM 'c:\temp\proficiency_objective.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\proficiency_objective_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)

BULK INSERT eval.proficiency_test_template
FROM 'c:\temp\proficiency_test_template.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\proficiency_test_template_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)

BULK INSERT eval.proficiency_test_template_session
FROM 'c:\temp\proficiency_test_template_session.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\proficiency_test_template_session__error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)
        

BULK INSERT eval.proficiency_test
FROM 'c:\temp\proficiency_test.csv'
WITH
(
KEEPIDENTITY,
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\proficiency_test_error_file.txt',
TABLOCK
)
```

-- Queries to run student result reports

```
SELECT ds.first_name, ds.last_name,
(dps.session_desc + ' - ' + dps.season) as TestDate,
pc.shot_category as Section,
po.shot_objective as Round,
pt.score,
ptt.score_attempts,
ROUND(CAST((pt.score * 100.0 / ptt.score_attempts) AS FLOAT), 1) AS Percentage,
 pc.proficiency_category_id, po.proficiency_objective_id 
FROM eval.proficiency_test                  pt
  JOIN eval.proficiency_test_template           ptt on pt.proficiency_objective_id = ptt.proficiency_objective_id
  JOIN eval.proficiency_test_template_session   ptts on ptt.template_num = ptts.template_num and pt.program_session_id = ptts.program_session_id
  JOIN eval.proficiency_objective               po  on ptt.proficiency_objective_id = po.proficiency_objective_id
  JOIN eval.proficiency_category                pc  on po.proficiency_category_id = pc.proficiency_category_id
  JOIN eval.student                             ds  on pt.student_id = ds.student_id
  JOIN eval.program_session                     dps on pt.program_id = dps.program_id and ptts.program_session_id = dps.program_session_id
WHERE (dps.session_desc + ' - ' + dps.season) in ('Main Session 3 - 2020-21', 'Main Session 4 - 2020-21')
AND ds.first_name ='Test Student11'
ORDER BY ds.first_name, ds.last_name,
  (dps.session_desc + ' - ' + dps.season), pc.proficiency_category_id, po.proficiency_objective_id
```

Here are the contents of the csv files

```
[student.csv]
student_id,first_name,last_name,phone,email,DOB,note,in_transition,is_active
1,Test Student1,,,,,,Y,Y
2,Test Student2,,,,,,Y,Y
3,Test Student3,,,,,,Y,Y
4,Test Student4,,,,,,Y,Y
5,Test Student5,,,,,,Y,Y
6,Test Student6,,,,,,Y,Y
7,Test Student7,,,,,,Y,Y
8,Test Student8,,,,,,Y,Y
9,Test Student9,,,,,,Y,Y
10,Test Student10,,,,,,Y,Y
11,Test Student11,,,,,,Y,Y
12,Test Student12,,,,,,Y,Y
13,Test Student13,,,,,,Y,Y
15,Test Student14,,,,,,Y,Y
16,Test Student15,,,,,,Y,Y
17,Test Student16,,,,,,Y,Y
18,Test Student17,,,,,,Y,Y
19,Test Student18,,,,,,Y,Y
20,Test Student19,,,,,,Y,Y
21,Test Student20,,,,,,Y,Y
22,Test Student21,,,,,,Y,Y
23,Test Student22,,,,,,Y,Y
24,Test Student23,,,,,,Y,Y
25,Test Student24,,,,,,Y,Y
26,Test Student25,,,,,,Y,Y
27,Test Student26,,,,,,Y,Y

[program.csv]
program_id,program_desc
1,High Performance
2,Love to Learn 101
3,Love to Learn 102
4,Junior Varsity
5,Full Court
6,Red Ball 1
7,Red Ball 2
8,HP Summer Camp
9,Orange Ball 1
10,Orange Ball 2

[program_session.csv]
program_session_id,program_id,session_desc,season,session_start_date,session_end_date
1,1,Main Session 1,2020-21,8/31/2020 0:00,10/24/2020 0:00
2,1,Main Session 2,2020-21,11/2/2020 0:00,1/16/2021 0:00
3,1,Main Session 3,2020-21,1/25/2021 0:00,3/20/2021 0:00
4,1,Main Sespsion 4,2020-21,3/29/2021 0:00,5/22/2021 0:00
5,1,Main Session 1,2021-22,9/6/2021 0:00,10/31/2021 0:00
6,1,Main Session 2,2021-22,11/1/2021 0:00,1/16/2022 0:00
7,1,Main Session 3,2021-22,1/17/2022 0:00,3/13/2022 0:00
8,1,Main Session 4,2021-22,3/21/2022 0:00,5/15/2022 0:00

[proficiency_objective.csv]
Proficiency_Objective_id,Proficiency_Category_id,Shot Objective,Shot Objective_Desc,Score_attempts
1,1,10 crosscourt forehand drives for accuracy (any spin),,10
2,1,6 crosscourt underspin forehands ,,6
3,1,10 down-the-line forehands for accuracy (any spin),,10
4,2,10 crosscourt backhand drives for accuracy (any spin),,10
5,2,6 crosscourt underspin backhands,,6
6,2,10 down-the-line backhands for accuracy (any spin),,10
7,3,6 forehand lobs,,6
8,3,6 backhand lobs,,6
9,4,6 low forehand volleys,,6
11,4,6 low backhand volleys,,6
13,4,6 overheads alternating,,6
14,4,6 scissor-kick overheads,,6
15,5,6 forehand dropshots,,6
16,5,6 backhand dropshots,,6
17,6,6 serves for accuracy from Duece-Wide,,6
18,6,6 serves for accuracy from Duece-T,,6
19,6,6 serves for accuracy from Ad-T,,6
20,6,6 serves for accuracy from Ad-Wide,,6
21,6,3 topspin serves from Ad-Wide,,3
22,6,3 slice serves from Duece-Wide,,3
23,7,6 four-ball pickups on the minute,,6
24,7,7 four-ball pickups on the minute,,7
25,7,8 four-ball pickups on the minute,,8
26,8,Mental,,10
27,8,Mental,,15

[proficiency_category.csv]
Proficiency_category_id ,shot_category,shot_category_desc
1,Forehand,
2,Backhand,
3,Lob,
4,Volley/Overhead,
5,Dropshot,
6,Serve,
7,Conditioning,
8,Mental,

[proficiency_test_template.csv]
proficiency_test_template_id,template_num,proficiency_objective_id,score_attempts
1,1,1,10
2,1,2,6
3,1,3,10
4,1,4,10
5,1,5,6
6,1,6,10
7,1,7,6
8,1,8,6
9,1,9,6
10,1,11,6
11,1,13,6
12,1,14,6
13,1,15,6
14,1,16,6
15,2,1,10
16,2,2,6
17,2,3,10
18,2,4,10
19,2,5,6
20,2,6,10
21,2,7,6
22,2,8,6
23,2,9,6
24,2,11,6
25,2,13,6
26,2,14,6
27,2,15,6
28,2,16,6
29,2,17,6
30,2,18,6
31,2,19,6
32,2,20,6
33,2,21,3
34,2,22,3
35,2,23,6
36,3,1,10
37,3,2,6
38,3,3,10
39,3,4,10
40,3,5,6
41,3,6,10
42,3,7,6
43,3,8,6
44,3,9,6
45,3,11,6
46,3,13,6
47,3,14,6
48,3,15,6
49,3,16,6
50,3,17,6
51,3,18,6
52,3,19,6
53,3,20,6
54,3,21,3
55,3,22,3
56,3,24,7
57,3,26,10

[proficiency_test_template_session.csv]
proficiency_test_template_session_id,template_num,program_session_id
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,2,3
4,3,4
5,3,5

[proficiency_test.csv]
3,1,1,1,3,3
3,1,1,2,4,3
3,1,1,2,5,3
3,1,1,2,6,4
3,1,1,3,7,2
3,1,1,3,8,2
3,1,1,4,9,3
3,1,1,4,11,1
3,1,1,4,13,3
3,1,1,4,14,5
3,1,1,5,15,5
3,1,1,5,16,2
3,1,2,1,1,5
3,1,2,1,2,6
3,1,2,1,3,4
3,1,2,2,4,8
3,1,2,2,5,5
3,1,2,2,6,7
3,1,2,3,7,3
3,1,2,3,8,2
3,1,2,4,9,1
3,1,2,4,11,2
3,1,2,4,13,3
3,1,2,4,14,5
3,1,2,5,15,5
3,1,2,5,16,2
3,1,2,6,17,3
3,1,2,6,18,5
3,1,2,6,19,1
3,1,2,6,20,3
3,1,2,6,21,2
3,1,2,6,22,0
3,1,2,7,23,2
3,1,4,1,1,4
3,1,4,1,2,5
3,1,4,1,3,5
3,1,4,2,4,3
3,1,4,2,5,3
3,1,4,2,6,4
3,1,4,3,7,1
3,1,4,3,8,1
3,1,4,4,9,0
3,1,4,4,11,3
3,1,4,4,13,3
3,1,4,4,14,1
3,1,4,5,15,1
3,1,4,5,16,1
3,1,4,6,17,3
3,1,4,6,18,3
3,1,4,6,19,5
3,1,4,6,20,4
3,1,4,6,21,1
3,1,4,6,22,2
3,1,4,7,24,2
4,1,4,1,1,8
4,1,4,1,2,2
4,1,4,1,3,4
4,1,4,2,4,3
4,1,4,2,5,2
4,1,4,2,6,6
4,1,4,3,7,1
4,1,4,3,8,2
4,1,4,4,9,0
4,1,4,4,11,2
4,1,4,4,13,3
4,1,4,4,14,1
4,1,4,5,15,4
4,1,4,5,16,1
4,1,4,6,17,2
4,1,4,6,18,3
4,1,4,6,19,2
4,1,4,6,20,2
4,1,4,6,21,0
4,1,4,6,22,3
4,1,4,7,24,7
5,1,1,1,1,8
5,1,1,1,2,4
5,1,1,1,3,6
5,1,1,2,4,4
5,1,1,2,5,3
5,1,1,2,6,8
5,1,1,3,7,5
5,1,1,3,8,4
5,1,1,4,9,4
5,1,1,4,11,3
5,1,1,4,13,4
5,1,1,4,14,4
5,1,1,5,15,3
5,1,1,5,16,4
5,1,1,8,24,2
5,1,2,1,1,7
5,1,2,1,2,4
5,1,2,1,3,5
5,1,2,2,4,5
5,1,2,2,5,3
5,1,2,2,6,6
5,1,2,3,7,6
5,1,2,3,8,6
5,1,2,4,9,5
5,1,2,4,11,3
5,1,2,4,13,4
5,1,2,4,14,3
5,1,2,5,15,2
5,1,2,5,16,3
5,1,2,6,17,4
5,1,2,6,18,3
5,1,2,6,19,4
5,1,2,6,20,3
5,1,2,6,21,0
5,1,2,6,22,2
5,1,2,7,23,2
5,1,3,1,1,10
5,1,3,1,2,3
5,1,3,1,3,8
5,1,3,2,4,7
5,1,3,2,5,5
5,1,3,2,6,6
5,1,3,3,7,5
5,1,3,3,8,4
5,1,3,4,9,1
5,1,3,4,11,3
5,1,3,4,13,6
5,1,3,4,14,5
5,1,3,5,15,4
5,1,3,5,16,2
5,1,3,6,17,6
5,1,3,6,18,6
5,1,3,6,19,4
5,1,3,6,20,6
5,1,3,6,21,3
5,1,3,6,22,2
5,1,3,7,23,2
5,1,4,1,1,9
5,1,4,1,2,5
5,1,4,1,3,6
5,1,4,2,4,6
5,1,4,2,5,3
5,1,4,2,6,7
5,1,4,3,7,2
5,1,4,3,8,4
5,1,4,4,9,3
5,1,4,4,11,4
5,1,4,4,13,6
5,1,4,4,14,5
5,1,4,5,15,2
5,1,4,5,16,3
5,1,4,6,17,5
5,1,4,6,18,4
5,1,4,6,19,6
5,1,4,6,20,5
5,1,4,6,21,1
5,1,4,6,22,1
5,1,4,7,24,2
6,1,1,1,1,6
6,1,1,1,2,3
6,1,1,1,3,2
6,1,1,2,4,9
6,1,1,2,5,4
6,1,1,2,6,6
6,1,1,3,7,5
6,1,1,3,8,3
6,1,1,4,9,3
6,1,1,4,11,4
6,1,1,4,13,5
6,1,1,4,14,2
6,1,1,5,15,2
6,1,1,5,16,2
6,1,3,1,1,3
6,1,3,1,2,2
6,1,3,1,3,7
6,1,3,2,4,7
6,1,3,2,5,2
6,1,3,2,6,4
6,1,3,3,7,2
6,1,3,3,8,3
6,1,3,4,9,5
6,1,3,4,11,4
6,1,3,4,13,4
6,1,3,4,14,3
6,1,3,5,15,2
6,1,3,5,16,4
6,1,3,6,17,2
6,1,3,6,18,2
6,1,3,6,19,4
6,1,3,6,20,4
6,1,3,6,21,1
6,1,3,6,22,1
6,1,3,7,23,2
6,1,4,1,1,9
6,1,4,1,2,3
6,1,4,1,3,4
6,1,4,2,4,3
6,1,4,2,5,2
6,1,4,2,6,2
6,1,4,3,7,5
6,1,4,3,8,5
6,1,4,4,9,2
6,1,4,4,11,3
6,1,4,4,13,4
6,1,4,4,14,5
6,1,4,5,15,3
6,1,4,5,16,3
6,1,4,6,17,4
6,1,4,6,18,3
6,1,4,6,19,3
6,1,4,6,20,5
6,1,4,6,21,0
6,1,4,6,22,1
6,1,4,7,24,2
7,1,1,1,1,5
7,1,1,1,2,4
7,1,1,1,3,7
7,1,1,2,4,6
7,1,1,2,5,5
7,1,1,2,6,5
7,1,1,3,7,3
7,1,1,3,8,6
7,1,1,4,9,2
7,1,1,4,11,3
7,1,1,4,13,3
7,1,1,4,14,2
7,1,1,5,15,4
7,1,1,5,16,3
7,1,3,1,1,6
7,1,3,1,2,5
7,1,3,1,3,6
7,1,3,2,4,8
7,1,3,2,5,3
7,1,3,2,6,6
7,1,3,3,7,4
7,1,3,3,8,3
7,1,3,4,9,2
7,1,3,4,11,3
7,1,3,4,13,2
7,1,3,4,14,3
7,1,3,5,15,4
7,1,3,5,16,6
7,1,3,6,17,3
7,1,3,6,18,3
7,1,3,6,19,3
7,1,3,6,20,2
7,1,3,6,21,0
7,1,3,6,22,1
7,1,3,7,23,4
7,1,4,1,1,7
7,1,4,1,2,4
7,1,4,1,3,4
7,1,4,2,4,6
7,1,4,2,5,5
7,1,4,2,6,5
7,1,4,3,7,2
7,1,4,3,8,4
7,1,4,4,9,3
7,1,4,4,11,4
7,1,4,4,13,5
7,1,4,4,14,4
7,1,4,5,15,0
7,1,4,5,16,3
7,1,4,6,17,3
7,1,4,6,18,4
7,1,4,6,19,4
7,1,4,6,20,1
7,1,4,6,21,3
7,1,4,6,22,1
7,1,4,7,24,6
8,1,1,1,1,8
8,1,1,1,2,2
8,1,1,1,3,6
8,1,1,2,4,4
8,1,1,2,5,3
8,1,1,2,6,5
8,1,1,3,7,0
8,1,1,3,8,4
8,1,1,4,9,4
8,1,1,4,11,3
8,1,1,4,13,4
8,1,1,4,14,6
8,1,1,5,15,2
8,1,1,5,16,4
8,1,2,1,1,6
8,1,2,1,2,2
8,1,2,1,3,5
8,1,2,2,4,2
8,1,2,2,5,3
8,1,2,2,6,4
8,1,2,3,7,1
8,1,2,3,8,3
8,1,2,4,9,1
8,1,2,4,11,4
8,1,2,4,13,3
8,1,2,4,14,2
8,1,2,5,15,2
8,1,2,5,16,3
8,1,2,6,17,2
8,1,2,6,18,3
8,1,2,6,19,3
8,1,2,6,20,2
8,1,2,6,21,1
8,1,2,6,22,0
8,1,2,7,23,3
8,1,3,1,1,6
8,1,3,1,2,2
8,1,3,1,3,6
8,1,3,2,4,4
8,1,3,2,5,2
8,1,3,2,6,4
8,1,3,3,7,1
8,1,3,3,8,1
8,1,3,4,9,3
8,1,3,4,11,2
8,1,3,4,13,1
8,1,3,4,14,3
8,1,3,5,15,3
8,1,3,5,16,3
8,1,3,6,17,0
8,1,3,6,18,4
8,1,3,6,19,3
8,1,3,6,20,3
8,1,3,6,21,2
8,1,3,6,22,1
8,1,3,7,23,3
8,1,4,1,1,7
8,1,4,1,2,5
8,1,4,1,3,7
8,1,4,2,4,6
8,1,4,2,5,2
8,1,4,2,6,7
8,1,4,3,7,5
8,1,4,3,8,2
8,1,4,4,9,3
8,1,4,4,11,2
8,1,4,4,13,3
8,1,4,4,14,3
8,1,4,5,15,1
8,1,4,5,16,1
8,1,4,6,17,3
8,1,4,6,18,5
8,1,4,6,19,4
8,1,4,6,20,4
8,1,4,6,21,0
8,1,4,6,22,1
8,1,4,7,24,4
9,1,1,1,1,7
9,1,1,1,2,5
9,1,1,1,3,8
9,1,1,2,4,4
9,1,1,2,5,4
9,1,1,2,6,6
9,1,1,3,7,3
9,1,1,3,8,5
9,1,1,4,9,3
9,1,1,4,11,3
9,1,1,4,13,4
9,1,1,4,14,3
9,1,1,5,15,3
9,1,1,5,16,6
10,1,2,1,1,8
10,1,2,1,2,4
10,1,2,1,3,3
10,1,2,2,4,8
10,1,2,2,5,4
10,1,2,2,6,4
10,1,2,3,7,4
10,1,2,3,8,5
10,1,2,4,9,4
10,1,2,4,11,3
10,1,2,4,13,4
10,1,2,4,14,5
10,1,2,5,15,2
10,1,2,5,16,5
10,1,2,6,17,2
10,1,2,6,18,4
10,1,2,6,19,4
10,1,2,6,20,6
10,1,2,6,21,3
10,1,2,6,22,0
10,1,2,7,23,2
10,1,3,1,1,9
10,1,3,1,2,3
10,1,3,1,3,5
10,1,3,2,4,6
10,1,3,2,5,2
10,1,3,2,6,5
10,1,3,3,7,0
10,1,3,3,8,2
10,1,3,4,9,2
10,1,3,4,11,1
10,1,3,4,13,5
10,1,3,4,14,4
10,1,3,5,15,3
10,1,3,5,16,2
10,1,3,6,17,2
10,1,3,6,18,5
10,1,3,6,19,4
10,1,3,6,20,4
10,1,3,6,21,1
10,1,3,6,22,1
10,1,3,7,23,2
10,1,4,1,1,8
10,1,4,1,2,4
10,1,4,1,3,4
10,1,4,2,4,6
10,1,4,2,5,1
10,1,4,2,6,2
10,1,4,3,7,5
10,1,4,3,8,4
10,1,4,4,9,0
10,1,4,4,11,2
10,1,4,4,13,3
10,1,4,4,14,2
10,1,4,5,15,4
10,1,4,5,16,2
10,1,4,6,17,4
10,1,4,6,18,5
10,1,4,6,19,4
10,1,4,6,20,4
10,1,4,6,21,0
10,1,4,6,22,0
10,1,4,7,24,4
11,1,1,1,1,8
11,1,1,1,2,4
11,1,1,1,3,4
11,1,1,2,4,6
11,1,1,2,5,3
11,1,1,2,6,4
11,1,1,3,7,3
11,1,1,3,8,4
11,1,1,4,9,3
11,1,1,4,11,4
11,1,1,4,13,4
11,1,1,4,14,3
11,1,1,5,15,2
11,1,1,5,16,4
11,1,3,1,1,3
11,1,3,1,2,3
11,1,3,1,3,5
11,1,3,2,4,7
11,1,3,2,5,3
11,1,3,2,6,6
11,1,3,3,7,3
11,1,3,3,8,4
11,1,3,4,9,1
11,1,3,4,11,2
11,1,3,4,13,4
11,1,3,4,14,4
11,1,3,5,15,3
11,1,3,5,16,3
11,1,3,6,17,4
11,1,3,6,18,2
11,1,3,6,19,2
11,1,3,6,20,5
11,1,3,6,21,0
11,1,3,6,22,0
11,1,3,7,23,6
11,1,4,1,1,7
11,1,4,1,2,3
11,1,4,1,3,5
11,1,4,2,4,9
11,1,4,2,5,2
11,1,4,2,6,5
11,1,4,3,7,3
11,1,4,3,8,3
11,1,4,4,9,2
11,1,4,4,11,4
11,1,4,4,13,3
11,1,4,4,14,4
11,1,4,5,15,4
11,1,4,5,16,3
11,1,4,6,17,5
11,1,4,6,18,3
11,1,4,6,19,5
11,1,4,6,20,3
11,1,4,6,21,0
11,1,4,6,22,1
11,1,4,7,24,7
12,1,1,1,1,5
12,1,1,1,2,6
12,1,1,1,3,8
12,1,1,2,4,6
12,1,1,2,5,3
12,1,1,2,6,5
12,1,1,3,7,4
12,1,1,3,8,5
12,1,1,4,9,3
12,1,1,4,11,4
12,1,1,4,13,6
12,1,1,4,14,5
12,1,1,5,15,3
12,1,1,5,16,2
12,1,1,8,24,2
12,1,2,1,1,6
12,1,2,1,2,2
12,1,2,1,3,6
12,1,2,2,4,3
12,1,2,2,5,2
12,1,2,2,6,6
12,1,2,3,7,1
12,1,2,3,8,2
12,1,2,4,9,5
12,1,2,4,11,4
12,1,2,4,13,6
12,1,2,4,14,3
12,1,2,5,15,5
12,1,2,5,16,4
12,1,2,6,17,5
12,1,2,6,18,4
12,1,2,6,19,5
12,1,2,6,20,3
12,1,2,6,21,0
12,1,2,6,22,1
12,1,2,7,23,0
17,1,3,1,1,8
17,1,3,1,2,5
17,1,3,1,3,5
17,1,3,2,4,7
17,1,3,2,5,5
17,1,3,2,6,6
17,1,3,3,7,2
17,1,3,3,8,0
17,1,3,4,9,3
17,1,3,4,11,2
17,1,3,4,13,5
17,1,3,4,14,4
17,1,3,5,15,3
17,1,3,5,16,3
17,1,3,6,17,1
17,1,3,6,18,4
17,1,3,6,19,3
17,1,3,6,20,2
17,1,3,6,21,0
17,1,3,6,22,0
17,1,3,7,23,3
17,1,4,1,1,8
17,1,4,1,2,3
17,1,4,1,3,7
17,1,4,2,4,6
17,1,4,2,5,3
17,1,4,2,6,3
17,1,4,3,7,3
17,1,4,3,8,2
17,1,4,4,9,2
17,1,4,4,11,1
17,1,4,4,13,6
17,1,4,4,14,4
17,1,4,5,15,4
17,1,4,5,16,1
17,1,4,6,17,2
17,1,4,6,18,3
17,1,4,6,19,3
17,1,4,6,20,1
17,1,4,6,21,0
17,1,4,6,22,2
17,1,4,7,24,4
18,1,3,1,1,5
18,1,3,1,2,1
18,1,3,1,3,2
18,1,3,2,4,5
18,1,3,2,5,0
18,1,3,2,6,1
18,1,3,3,7,3
18,1,3,3,8,2
18,1,3,4,9,0
18,1,3,4,11,1
18,1,3,4,13,2
18,1,3,4,14,3
18,1,3,5,15,1
18,1,3,5,16,0
18,1,3,6,17,4
18,1,3,6,18,3
18,1,3,6,19,3
18,1,3,6,20,3
18,1,3,6,21,0
18,1,3,6,22,0
18,1,3,7,23,3
19,1,3,1,1,5
19,1,3,1,2,3
19,1,3,1,3,6
19,1,3,2,4,4
19,1,3,2,5,2
19,1,3,2,6,4
19,1,3,3,7,1
19,1,3,3,8,3
19,1,3,4,9,1
19,1,3,4,11,3
19,1,3,4,13,3
19,1,3,4,14,1
19,1,3,5,15,0
19,1,3,5,16,0
19,1,3,6,17,4
19,1,3,6,18,5
19,1,3,6,19,5
19,1,3,6,20,5
19,1,3,6,21,0
19,1,3,6,22,0
19,1,3,7,23,1
19,1,4,1,1,5
19,1,4,1,2,2
19,1,4,1,3,2
19,1,4,2,4,3
19,1,4,2,5,2
19,1,4,2,6,5
19,1,4,3,7,2
19,1,4,3,8,3
19,1,4,4,9,3
19,1,4,4,11,0
19,1,4,4,13,3
19,1,4,4,14,1
19,1,4,5,15,0
19,1,4,5,16,1
19,1,4,6,17,5
19,1,4,6,18,4
19,1,4,6,19,6
19,1,4,6,20,5
19,1,4,6,21,0
19,1,4,6,22,0
19,1,4,7,24,3
20,1,3,1,1,6
20,1,3,1,2,4
20,1,3,1,3,3
20,1,3,2,4,6
20,1,3,2,5,2
20,1,3,2,6,4
20,1,3,3,7,6
20,1,3,3,8,5
20,1,3,4,9,5
20,1,3,4,11,3
20,1,3,4,13,6
20,1,3,4,14,1
20,1,3,5,15,4
20,1,3,5,16,2
20,1,3,6,17,2
20,1,3,6,18,5
20,1,3,6,19,4
20,1,3,6,20,4
20,1,3,6,21,0
20,1,3,6,22,0
20,1,3,7,23,2
20,1,4,1,1,5
20,1,4,1,2,4
20,1,4,1,3,3
20,1,4,2,4,3
20,1,4,2,5,3
20,1,4,2,6,3
20,1,4,3,7,5
20,1,4,3,8,3
20,1,4,4,9,2
20,1,4,4,11,3
20,1,4,4,13,3
20,1,4,4,14,4
20,1,4,5,15,3
20,1,4,5,16,2
20,1,4,6,17,4
20,1,4,6,18,2
20,1,4,6,19,3
20,1,4,6,20,5
20,1,4,6,21,0
20,1,4,6,22,1
20,1,4,7,24,7
21,1,3,1,1,5
21,1,3,1,2,4
21,1,3,1,3,8
21,1,3,2,4,6
21,1,3,2,5,2
21,1,3,2,6,3
21,1,3,3,7,4
21,1,3,3,8,3
21,1,3,4,9,1
21,1,3,4,11,2
21,1,3,4,13,2
21,1,3,4,14,3
21,1,3,5,15,4
21,1,3,5,16,6
21,1,3,6,17,1
21,1,3,6,18,5
21,1,3,6,19,5
21,1,3,6,20,3
21,1,3,6,21,0
21,1,3,6,22,3
21,1,3,7,23,3
24,1,4,1,1,6
24,1,4,1,2,3
24,1,4,1,3,1
24,1,4,2,4,1
24,1,4,2,5,2
24,1,4,2,6,2
24,1,4,3,7,1
24,1,4,3,8,3
24,1,4,4,9,3
24,1,4,4,11,3
24,1,4,4,13,2
24,1,4,4,14,3
24,1,4,5,15,2
24,1,4,5,16,2
24,1,4,6,17,3
24,1,4,6,18,3
24,1,4,6,19,3
24,1,4,6,20,2
24,1,4,6,21,1
24,1,4,6,22,1
24,1,4,7,24,4
25,1,4,1,1,7
25,1,4,1,2,2
25,1,4,1,3,4
25,1,4,2,4,6
25,1,4,2,5,0
25,1,4,2,6,5
25,1,4,3,7,4
25,1,4,3,8,1
25,1,4,4,9,0
25,1,4,4,11,1
25,1,4,4,13,0
25,1,4,4,14,4
25,1,4,5,15,0
25,1,4,5,16,4
25,1,4,6,17,2
25,1,4,6,18,4
25,1,4,6,19,0
25,1,4,6,20,2
25,1,4,6,21,0
25,1,4,6,22,1
25,1,4,7,24,4
26,1,4,1,1,6
26,1,4,1,2,3
26,1,4,1,3,6
26,1,4,2,4,5
26,1,4,2,5,0
26,1,4,2,6,5
26,1,4,3,7,0
26,1,4,3,8,5
26,1,4,4,9,5
26,1,4,4,11,2
26,1,4,4,13,4
26,1,4,4,14,5
26,1,4,5,15,4
26,1,4,5,16,3
26,1,4,6,17,2
26,1,4,6,18,4
26,1,4,6,19,4
26,1,4,6,20,4
26,1,4,6,21,0
26,1,4,6,22,1
26,1,4,7,24,4
27,1,4,1,1,5
27,1,4,1,2,2
27,1,4,1,3,1
27,1,4,2,4,2
27,1,4,2,5,1
27,1,4,2,6,1
27,1,4,3,7,1
27,1,4,3,8,1
27,1,4,4,9,3
27,1,4,4,11,2
27,1,4,4,13,3
27,1,4,4,14,1
27,1,4,5,15,2
27,1,4,5,16,1
27,1,4,6,17,3
27,1,4,6,18,0
27,1,4,6,19,3
27,1,4,6,20,1
27,1,4,6,21,0
27,1,4,6,22,1
27,1,4,7,24,2
```

Comment: Is this in 3rd normal form?  No - you do not have any keys (which 3NF would require).  You have row identifiers.  Case in point, this insert would be allowed to succeed: `INSERT INTO eval.program_session VALUES (1,'Main Session 1','2020-21','2020-08-31 00:00','2020-10-24 00:00'), (1,'Main Session 1','2020-21','2020-08-31 00:00','2020-10-24 00:00'), (1,'Main Session 1','2020-21','2020-08-31 00:00','2020-10-24 00:00'), (1,'Main Session 1','2020-21','2020-08-31 00:00','2020-10-24 00:00'), (1,'Main Session 1','2020-21','2020-08-31 00:00','2020-10-24 00:00')`

Comment: My advice: don't code it, draw it.  Find which elements of the *data* determine uniqueness - those are your keys (student_id is fine - people are a little more complex to keep unique and that's not always feasible within the database).  You will have composite keys, that's fine and you should embrace them.